# How to change the stylesheet of the left-over docking space?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QtDockWidget whose widget is set to a fixed size. When I dock this widget into my fixed-size main window, it leaves a left over grey/white space. How can I affect the stylesheet of this left over space?

I have tried changing the style sheets of every widget/window in my program, none seem to affect this area.

I don't have enough reputation to post an image, so here it is:

[image]

The area I'm talking about is the white space below the RESET DATA button; I can't seem to find any other questions or references to this space anywhere. Thank you

Comment: This is a worthwhile use of an image. Wish I knew QT well enough to reward you with an answer.

Comment: Hello , you can show your code? as I understand it, you  set in QtDockWidget  fix size widget ?